# Show using Stirling's approx. that $\log\binom{n}{\gamma n} = nh(\gamma) -\frac{1}{2} \log n + O(1).$

Tags: information-theory

Let $h(p) = -p \log p-(1-p)\log (1-p)$ denote the binary entropy of a Bernoulli distribution when the probability of observing a zero is $p$, where $\log$ denotes the logarithm to base 2. Show, using Stirling's approximation:

$$ \ln(n!)  = (n+\frac{1}{2})\ln(n) - n + O(1)$$

that the following holds:

$$\log\binom{n}{\gamma n} = nh(\gamma) -\frac{1}{2} \log n + O(1).$$

How should I do this? I'd like a hint to get me started.

Comment: Hint 1: $$\binom{n}{\gamma n} = \frac{n!}{(\gamma n)!((1-\gamma)n)!}.$$  Hint 2: $$\log\left(\frac{a}{bc}\right) = \log a - \log b - \log c.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas Does Stirling's approximation only hold for the natural logarithm? Where am I supposed to make the switch from ln to log?

Comment: It does only hold for the natural logarithm, but all you need to do is use $\log_2 x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$ to switch between them.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I have been busy for hours with this, and still can't solve it. I write it out using the hints above, but it just doesnt work. For example, I can't manage to obtain the $\log(\gamma)$ from the initial formula. Could you maybe exound it a little more?